# Visual Studio Code MacOS bar customize

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't change the background of this element on vscode (cf. image below)
[image]

I tried setting `tab.activeBackground` but it changes nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make the config changes inside `workbench.colorCustomizations`? The following lines inside `settings.json` work for me

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "tab.activeBackground": "#ff0000"
}
```

and produce a red background for the currently selected tab

[image: tab of the selected file in red]